# Ordinary differential equation with variable (polynomial) coefficients -form of solution

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

If you have a differential equation with polynomial  coefficients then quite remarkably Mathematica can find a solution.  For example for the second order differential equation

$ y''(t)+b y'(t)+\left(\text{c0}+\text{c1} t+\text{c2} t^2+\text{c3} t^3\right) y(t) $

where the coefficient of y(t) is a polynomial in *t* we can get a solution from `DSolve`

```
eqn = y''[t] + b y'[t] + (c0 + c1 t + c2 t^2 + c3 t^3) y[t] == 0;

sol = y[t] /. First@DSolve[eqn, y[t], t]
```

[image]

By clicking on the icon we can get some more information

[image]

If we put in values we can plot

```
vals = {c0 -> 10, c1 -> 0.5, c2 -> 0.2, c3 -> 0.1, b -> 0.1, 
   C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 1};
Plot[Evaluate[sol /. vals], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

The solution may be used to do algebraic calculation. Here I take the derivative and plot on the phase plane.

```
dsol = D[sol, t];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{sol, dsol} /. vals], {t, 0, 10}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

However, I would really like to know what the function looks like.  `FunctionExpand` and `DifferentialRootReduce` do nothing.

```
sol // FunctionExpand
DifferentialRootReduce[sol, t]
```

I know that the  function behind `DifferentialRoot` is probably so complicated and long that it is difficult to understand and do anything useful with. However, the general form may be useful.  I am curious and would like to see the function behind the icon. Can this be done?

Comment: You are right, the analytic solution of such an ODE [homogeneous second order differential equation with non-constant coefficients] is too complicated. However, it exists and the algorithm is known due to [Kovacic](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0747-7171(86)80010-4). For higher orders it is known that linear ODEs do not have a general solution [Picard–Vessiot theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard–Vessiot_theory).

Comment: If in your equation c3=0, the solution can be expressed in terms of linear combination of `BesselJ` and `BesselY` of order 1/3.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.  We can get a glimpse of the solution by working out the series around some point, This shows some structure but is not quite what I was hoping for.

Comment: Your may also find relevant Nikiforov-Uvarov formalism  https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0604021.pdf .

Comment: @Acus, thank you. If you know something about this area a chat would be good.

Comment: @Hugh  When I was student we learned that method and later  I even made Mathematica notebook (for versions 7 to 9). Though the notebook is in local language it contains all relevant formulas and Mathematica implementation. Can download it from here:  http://spektras.itpa.lt/~acus/Hugh/

Comment: If you want a **series** solution: `eqn = y''[t] + b y'[t] + (c0 + c1 t + c2 t^2 + c3 t^3) y[t] == 
  0; AsymptoticDSolveValue[eqn, y[t], {t, 0, 5}]` .

Answer (score 1):

The manual/help for `DifferentialRoot` says " `FunctionExpand` will attempt to expand DifferentialRoot objects in terms of ordinary special and elementary functions."

Test it for various combinations with Manipulate. E.g. for all c4 == 0 or for (c1 and c2 and c3 and b) == 0 you get explicit functions.

```
eqn = y''[t] + b y'[t] + (c0 + c1 t + c2 t^2 + c3 t^3) y[t] == 0;

ysol[d1_, d2_, b_, c0_, c1_, c2_, c3_] = 
  y /. First@DSolve[eqn && y[0] == d1 && y'[0] == d2, y, t]

Manipulate[{Plot[
  Evaluate[ysol[d1, d2, b, c1, c2, c3, c4][t]], {t, 0, 7}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
   ysol[d1, d2, b, c1, c2, c3, c4][t] // FunctionExpand[#, Assumptions -> t > 0] &}, {{d1, 1}, 0, 
   4, 1/100, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{d2, 2}, 0, 3, 1/100, 
 Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 1}, 0, 3, 1/100, 
 Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c1, 1}, 0, 4, 1/100, 
 Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c2, 1}, 0, 4, 1/100, 
 Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c3, 1}, 0, 4, 1/100, 
 Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c4, 1}, 0, 4, 1/100, 
 Appearance -> "Labeled"}, ContinuousAction -> False]
```

Comment: Thanks. I had looked at this. It is not clear how the simpler forms progress to the one I want to see. Any ideas?